# Tables in SSRS not appearing as required

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following report..

[image]

The first table expands to include all 12 months of the year. Underneath I have 2 tables that I would like to get adjacent to each other. The result is...

[image]

As you can see, the table on the right is over to the far right of the screen. I have tried putting the two tables at the bottom inside a rectangle, but get the same result.

**How can i get these two tables to appear adjacent to each other and both underneath the top table?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you said you tried putting them in a rectangle but this **is** how you do it.

Make sure you didn't just drag them over the rectangle, the correct procedure for existing tables is to cut then paste inside the rectangle.

Here's my tests to show the desired effect.

First the design with no rectangle.
[image]

This give this output, the same result you are getting.
[image]

Next I added a rectangle then **cut and pasted** each table making sure I right-click inside the rectangle when pasting.
[image]

Which gives this output.
[image]